# TypeError: undefined is not a function when serializing a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am new to js and am trying to serialize the values in a form to get it ready for submission into ajax.

In my browser, I get this error and I am not sure why:

```
$('#myform').serializeObject()
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is the code I am running:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Hello there! How are you?");
    mydata = JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeObject());
    console.log(mydata);
});
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qqoupsyb/) I created to make it easier. I thought the problem could be in `serializeObject`, but the debugger does not even get to that point.

**UPDATE**

Though I corrected this typo (which came up while I was creating the post), I get the same error. I tried this is firefox, and I got `TypeError: $(...).serializeObject is not a function`. Strangely, it works fine on jsfiddle.

Comment: your code seems a bit off with the `JSON.stringify` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I had been calling my script before jquery was being loaded and therefore I was getting that error message. Duh. I am embarrassed, but wanted to post this just in case it can benefit someone.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the $.serialize() function from JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("Hello there! How are you?");
    mydata = JSON.stringify($('#myform').serialize());
    console.log(mydata);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use jQuery's built in methods:

serialize: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

or

param: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Or are you doing anything especially custom there?

Answer (score 0):

You've had a typo or a mistake, you used `JSON.stringify` directly on jQuery object, instead of on the result of `.serializeObject()`

**Before:**

```
JSON.stringify($('#myform')).serializeObject());
```

**After:**

```
mydata = JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeObject());
```

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gz3Lbkcj/1/

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made a mistake while I was typing my code and the question. The problem still remains but it shows up fine on jsfiddle.. I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is like re-inventing the wheel but try replacing following statement:

```
mydata = JSON.stringify($('#myform')).serializeObject());
```

with

```
mydata = JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeObject());
```

As `stringify` will return string representation of object and you will not be able to call `serializeObject` on it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made a mistake while I was typing my code and the question. The problem still remains but it shows up fine on jsfiddle.. I updated the question.